# Highcharts bubble chart with multiple series

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I am using highcharts to create bubble chart. I pass x,y and z co-ordinates as data. It displays circle with different radius with single legend entry at bottom. I need legend for individual circle in the bubble chart so i created different series for individual bubble. I got different legend but the size of circles are same. Please see my code below. Please let me know what is wrong in this. Thanks in advance

```
    $.each(input,function(index,value) {        
        red = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
        blue = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
        green = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);    
        color = red  + ',' + green + ',' + blue;
        chartData .push({
            name : value.departmentName,                
            marker: {
                symbol:'circle',
                fillColor:{
                        radialGradient: { cx: 0.5, cy: 0.3, r: 0.7 },
                        stops: [[0, 'rgba(255,255,255,0.5)'],[1, Highcharts.Color('rgba(' + color+ ',0.5)').brighten(-0.3).get('rgb')]]},

                lineColor:'rgba(' + color + ',.75)',
                lineWidth:1,           
                states:{
                    hover:{
                        enabled:false
                    }
                }
            },
            data: [{x:value.year, y:value.numberOfUsers, name: value.departmentName, marker: {radius:value.passcount,
                fillColor:{
                    radialGradient: { cx: 0.5, cy: 0.3, r: 0.7 },
                    stops: [[0, 'rgba(255,255,255,0.5)'],[1, Highcharts.Color('rgba(' + color+ ',0.5)').brighten(-0.3).get('rgb')]]}}, z : value.passcount}]
           });      

        });
        return chartData;

    

    ...

    


     function drawChart (chartData){
            //High charts
            var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
                chart: {
                    renderTo:'container',                       
                    type: 'bubble',
                    plotBorderWidth: 1 ,
                    zoomType: 'xy'
                },
                title:{
                    text:''
                },
                exporting:{
                    enabled : false
                },
               credits: {
                enabled: false
               },
                plotOptions: {
                    series: {
                        shadow:false,
                    }           
                },
                xAxis:{
                    minPadding:.075,
                    maxPadding:.075,
                    lineColor:'#999',
                    lineWidth:1,
                    tickColor:'#666',
                    tickLength:3,
                    title:{
                        text:'My chart'
                    }
                },
                yAxis:{
                    lineColor:'#999',
                    lineWidth:1,
                    tickColor:'#666',
                    tickWidth:1,
                    tickLength:3,
                    gridLineColor:'#ddd',
                    title:{
                        text:'Number Of Users',
                        rotation:270,
                        margin:10,
                    }
                },
                series: chartData

            });
```

[image: The output for above code is as below]

Answer (score 0):

As you know, Highcharts Bubbles are not yet officially released. However, in the latest development code, that bubble sizes are adjusted across series, so you are probably just loading some older code. Try running Highcharts from http://github.highcharts.com/rambera/highcharts.js and http://github.highcharts.com/rambera/highcharts-more.js.

Comment: I use same version you have mentioned. I even took latest from github but it gives lot of script errors

Comment: i found the cause for this issue. Since i am passing only one data for a series it shows same size for all circle. It expects more than one data in the series to show bubbles with different size. Is it possible to show legend for individual circle?